# GCDWebServer was built for newer iOS version (8.3) than being linked (7.0)

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ios9, gcdwebserver

I'm building my app using Ionic Framework and updating it for iOS 9 at this time.

My iOS Build Target is set to 9.0. So I'm not sure why it's trying to build for 8.3. Where can I change the build target for GCD Web Server and change the link from 7.0 to 9.0?

[image]

Comment: I'm getting this exact same error with Reapp.io so the problem is not specific to Ionic. I'm suspecting a problem with Cordova integration of GCD Web Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to figure out that `cordova-plugin-webserver` (required by `com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview`) is somehow incompatible with XCode 7 Beta.

The issue can be fixed by simply removing the compatible plugins:

```
cordova plugins remove com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview
cordova plugins remove cordova-plugin-webserver
```

This should work without any other modifications. **Do not change** iOS deployment targets or Enable Bitcode settings, they are just symptoms of the underlying problem and wont fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed the problem. I also removed the `cordova-plugin-webserver` plugin, which caused all the errors to disappear once I reverted my build settings back to their default state.

Comment: Good to hear! Fixed the answer to contain cordova-plugin-webserver, which I had also removed.

Comment: only removing `cordova-plugin-webserver` will work ? Do I have to remove the wkwebview plugin too?

Comment: @KaranKumar Wkwebview needs that as a dependency so yes, you need to remove both.

Answer (score -1):

It's the opposite: your app minimum deployment target is set to iOS 7.0, while GCDWebServer, in whatever way you are building it in your app (CocoaPods, Carthage, manual...), has its minimum deployment target set to 8.3.

Make sure the `iOS Deployment Target` in the build settings for your project and target(s) is correctly set to the same value and greater or equal than 8.3.

Comment: My `iOS Deployment Target` is set to 9.0 but still throws the same errors.

Comment: Also, I am building this app using the Ionic Framework. So no CocoaPods, or Carthage. I guess `npm` is kind of the equivalent in this case?

Comment: I disabled the `Enable Bitcode` setting on my Info tab and that caused many more of the same error to occur.

Comment: Then the ionic framework and its integration with GCDWebServer is misconfigured. The build settings are wrong in that project.